# How to make bootstrap 4 masorny column?

Tags: bootstrap-4, grid

[image: enter image description here*]

I am trying to take masorny type column in Bootstrap. But how to make this kind of grid in bootstrap 4?

Comment: you can give a green tick to my answer!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card-columns">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1600x900/483D8B/ffffff?text=Card+1" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card p-3">
      <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0 card-body">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
        <footer class="blockquote-footer">
          <small class="text-muted">
            Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
          </small>
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1600x450/9400D3/ffffff?text=Card+2" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card bg-primary text-white text-center p-3">
      <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat.</p>
        <footer class="blockquote-footer">
          <small>
            Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
          </small>
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="card text-center">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/1600x1600/FF1493/ffffff?text=Card+3" alt="Card image">
    </div>
    <div class="card p-3 text-right">
      <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
        <footer class="blockquote-footer">
          <small class="text-muted">
            Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
          </small>
        </footer>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap 4 masonry layout utilizing flexbox grid.

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="Description" content="Enter your description here" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <title>

    </title>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        .grid:after {
            display: block;
        }
        
        .grid-item {
            width: 160px;
            height: 120px;
            float: left;
            background: #17191E;
        }
        
        .grid-item--width2 {
            width: 300px;
        }
        
        .grid-item--width3 {
            width: 200px;
        }
        
        .grid-item--height2 {
            height: 400px;
        }
        
        .grid-item--height3 {
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="grid">
            <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2 grid-item--width2 "></div>
            <div class="grid-item grid-item--height3 grid-item--width2 " style="background-color: #F5D729;">
                <div style="padding: 20px;">
                    <h4><b>Super Awesome work</b></h4>
                    <div style="color: white; font-family: 'Tw Cen MT'; padding: 10px;"> work example textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample textexample
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="grid-item grid-item--height3 grid-item--width2 "></div>

            <div class="grid-item grid-item--height3 grid-item--width3 " style="background-color: #3C3B32;"></div>
            <div class="grid-item grid-item--height3 grid-item--width3 " style="background-color: #5D5C50;"></div>
            <div class="grid-item grid-item--height3 grid-item--width3 " style="#3C3B32"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z9ed5y8b/